# EntityFramework : FindBy (column name) select arbitrary column by expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a very simple code of what I am trying to achieve here.

Basically the idea here would be to be able to do a simple `FindBy(x => x.<the_column_name>, <the value>);` therefore I wouldn't have to copy-paste the same query by changing only the column name.

For now I keep getting an exception from LINQ saying `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Invoke(Spunky.Entities.User)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`

Is that something possible ? Or maybe we're not yet there with EF 6.1?

```
public class UsersRepository
{
  private Lazy<IDataContext> context;

  public UsersRepository()
    : this(() => new DataContext())
  {
  }

  public UsersRepository(Func<IDataContext> context)
  {
    this.context = new Lazy<IDataContext>(context);
  }

  public IQueryable<User> Find(int id)
  {
    return FindBy(u => u.Id, id);
  }

  public IQueryable<User> Find(string username)
  {
    return FindBy(u => u.Username, username);
  }

  public IQueryable<User> FindBy<T>(Func<User, T> property, T value)
  {
    return context.Value
            .Users
            .Where(u => property.Invoke(u).Equals(value));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the signature

```
IQueryable<User> FindBy(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate)
{
    return context.Users.Where(predicate);
}
```

you can call

```
return FindBy(u => u.Username == username);
```

The code hardly changes, but you don't need to manufacture expressions.

You have to enter an expression (not a `Func`) because expressions can be translated into SQL. A `Func` is just a .Net delegate, for which no SQL equivalent exists.

Comment: True it works, but then again, it render the Where useless in the fact that it's exactly the same. :/

Comment: Well, except that you still don't have a `Where` in the `Find` methods. It's just a *slightly* different way of parameterizing the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct an expression tree linq to entities can translate to sql:

```
public IQueryable<T> FindBy<TKey>(Expression<Func<T,TKey>> memberExpression, object value)
{
    var parameterVisitor = new ParameterVisitor(memberExpression);
    var parameter = parameterVisitor.Parameter;
    var constant = Expression.Constant(value);
    var equal = Expression.Equal(memberExpression,constant);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda(equal, parameter);
    return context.Value.Users.Where(predicate);
}

public class ParameterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
   public ParameterExpression Parameter { get;set;}
   public ParameterVisitor(Expression expr)
   {
       this.Visit(expr);
   }

   protected override VisitParameter(ParameterExpression parameter)
   {
        Parameter = parameter;
        return parameter;
    }

}
```

Still untested from the top of my head.

Edit: Code corrected.

Comment: Hum, nice idea, but `Expression.Equal()` render a `BinaryExpression` and the `Where` method requires either a `Func<T, Bool>` or a `Expression<Func<T, Bool>>` but I'll search with this in mind, maybe there is something to do here.

Comment: You are right. Forgot to make a lambda predicatel. See update.